# Oracle Command exception handling to differentiate if network/offline or syntax error,etc

Tags: c#, oracle

While executing sql statements I want to place my software in "offline mode" and save the sql statement to an offline file if a sql statement fails to execute because of a network issue.

What is the best way to tell if a sql statement fails because of a network issue. I want to differentiate failures: bad sql syntax, foreign key constraints, and network/db down.

Thanks for any help.

```
try
{
  using (var con = new OracleConnection(DBInfo.ConnectionString))
  {
    con.Open();

    var cmd = new OracleCommand
    {
      Connection = con,
      CommandText = sqlStatement,
      CommandType = CommandType.Text
    };
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  //how to differentiate failure types? 
  // if(offline exception) GoOffline();
```

Answer (score 0):

All oracle exceptions are handled by ODP and all throw `OracleException`

```
try{ . . . }
catch(OracleException ex){ . . . }
```

Each oracle exception has property `Message`, which will display plain old Oracle message like

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments

If you have network issues, you will get either standard Oracle network exeptions, i.g.

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Or, your provider timeout.

What you seem need is a queue that can be serialized in case of power shutdown or something like this. Don't save the sql, save the work. For example, serializable object that has all the values for your work and then some code that can be used to run DB call. For example

```
[Serializable]
public class CrudRequestModel
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;} 
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    . . . . .
}

public class CrudRequestProcessor
{
    public CrudRequestProcessor(CrudRequestModel m) {. . . }

    public bool Persist()
    {
        // code that will execute DB call
    }

    public bool SaveQueue(QueueConfig conf)
    {
        // code that will serialize and save model to file or whatever if DB call fails
    }
}
```

So your code will look like

```
var proc = new CrudRequestProcessor(model);
if (!proc.Persist())
    proc.SaveQueue(config);
```

Note, `SaveQueue` can be extension to make better single responsibility.